# Mac Mail app: Archive option issue

Tags: macos, gmail, osx-mavericks, apple-mail

I am using the Mail app with my Gmail account. What happens to my mail when I choose `archive`?

Where I can find this archived mail? Why don't I have an `Archived` folder? How can I set up an `Archived` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You archived Mail goes into the folder you created and pointed to when you created the archive rule.  You don't have an archive folder because you have to mount that folder you created in the mail app.  Look at this site for how to set up the rule https://discussions.apple.com/message/15315328#15315328